# Word 2010 Changing AutoText formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am having a weird issue with a Word 2000 Template being screwed up when saving it in Word 2010.

I have an autotext entry which is basically a table with some text, if I open the template in Word 2010, save it (without changing anything) close and then re-open it, the formatting for the autotext has changed. Some text has gone from bold to non-bold, font sizes have changed, etc.

I have tried deleting and re-defining the autotext but as soon as I save the template, the formatting goes again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting the formatting that is being lost on the autotext? For instance, apply bold formatting directly to the text as well as the associated style.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.

I had styles on the formatting and each time I saved the template file, and re-opened it, the AutoText lost the formatting.

Not sure I've found the answer but for the moment this has worked for me.
I "think" I discovered that the "only" way to save a template and preserve the AutoText formatting is by doing File > Save As.
If I click the Close button ... or ... do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> ... I think Word has saved my template, but when I re-open, I've lost the formatting on the AutoText.
File > Save As seems to be the only way Word 2010 will save the template and preserve the formatting.

I further discovered that the Close button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> also creates a `.dotx` file in the `Temporary Internet Files` that has about eight numbers/characters.  The Word template file inherits this alphanumeric template in the Building Blocks organizer.

Don't know if it works this way for everyone ... or whether is has something to do with the way Word is installed on the network at work.

I can't find anything about these alphanumeric template files on the internet!